# Gmail ломает картинки в html письмах

Tags: html, html5, email, sendmail, gmail

Есть HTML письмо с картинкой, которое рассылается клиентам. Почтовые клиенты нормально отображают картинку, но Web интерфейс Gmail нет. Он подставляет свой адрес в ссылку на изображение. Выглядит это так:

```
src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/{рандомный id}#{url картинки}"
```

Что необходимо сделать, чтобы гугл показывал картинку в письме?

Comment: Для начала нужно понять, почему у всех показывает, а у вас не показывает. Если подставить в письме любой другой url, например картинку на imgur.com — работает или нет? Не добавлялись ли какие-то ограничения на получение картинки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web интерфейс gmail все правильно делает. Это известная проблема: злоумышленник отправляет письмо с картинкой на своем сервере, пользователь просто открывает письмо, и злоумышленник получает его IP-адрес. Вы не сможете это обойти.

Вы можете попробовать вставлять данные в base64 напрямую в `src` атрибут.